# Change the color of text based on the value of it,via a button with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a newbie to the whole html,css and javascript world. i am required to create a button which changes the color of a text in a span based of the value that is written within a textbox.

This is what i managed to write so far:

```js
function changeColor() {
  var span = document.querySelector("span");
  if (span = 'purple') {
    span.style.color = 'purple';
  }
}
```

```css
.color {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <span>This text changes color</span>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="Type your input here">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Add Color" onclick="changeColor()">
    <input type="button" value="Clear all colors" onclick="ClearColors()">
  </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Homework3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *value* of the text input as the class name. Then you can use `classList.add()` property to add the class on the span element. You also do not need the clear button. You can use `classList.remove()` property to remove the class in the same function.

Try the following way:

```js
var span = document.querySelector("span");
var prevColor = '';
function changeColor() {
  var currentColor = document.querySelector("input[type='text']").value.trim();
  if(prevColor != '')
    span.classList.remove(prevColor);
  if(currentColor != ''){
    span.classList.add(currentColor);
    prevColor = currentColor;
  }
}
```

```css
.color {
    color:white;
    background-color: black;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.purple {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<span>This text changes color</span>
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type your input here">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Add Color" onclick="changeColor()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Solution**
It is not a good design pattern to hard-code your color classes in the css file since its the user that determine the needed color. You will limit the user's option by hard-coding the colors. what if the user key-in a color not in the css file. In view of the above, i created this solution:

Change the value attribute in input tag to placeholder i.e

```
From <input type="text" value="Type your input here">
to   <input type="text" placeholder="Type your input here">
```

Remove this from your html. its not necessary

```
<input type="button" value="Clear all colors" onclick="ClearColors()">
```

Replace the code in your javascript function with this

```
var span = document.querySelector("span");  
  var color = document.querySelector("input").value.trim();  
  span.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Here is the full source code:

```js
function changeColor() {
  var span = document.querySelector("span");
  var color = document.querySelector("input").value.trim();
  span.style.backgroundColor = color;
  //If you want to alter the color of text
  //span.style.color = 'any color';  
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Inputs and forms</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <span>This text changes color</span>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Type your input here">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Add Color" onclick="changeColor()">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

NOTE: CSS not needed